# Can't override back button on windows phone 7 landing page

Tags: windows-phone-7, back-button

I am working on a windows phone 7 application that requires a data connection.  If there is not one, it pops up an error message.

Per the app store requirements, I need to change the default behavior of the back button to close the popup first, instead of going back right away.

So, I found the following code, which works fine everywhere **except** for the landing page.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        }
```

The OnBackKeyPress event doesn't even get fired on the landing page.  It just goes back out of the application.  My landing page is a PhoneApplicationPage, the same as everywhere else.  I can't figure out why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. If you have a breakpoint set on the `e.Cancel = true;` line this shoudl get hit. Also, I hope that teh above code is also for example. You will need to add code to dismiss your popup.

Comment: @Matt - Yes, the code above is just an example.  Everywhere else in my code, the breakpoint gets hit.  However, on the landing page (a phoneapplicationpage loaded into a pivot control) I cannot get the event to fire.  It just exits out of the application.

Comment: @Neil I still can't recreate this (just retried with a Pivot Project). Can you create a new, minimal project which recreates this and make it available. Also, you have double checked that the breakpoint is set to "break always" haven't you.

Comment: youy said "phoneapplicationpage loaded *into* a pivotcontrol".  do you mean that the other way around?  the pivot should be in the page, not the other way around. if you have a page *inside* the pivot, (which would really be page->pivot->page?) then the outermost page would be getting the OnBackKeyPress, not the inner one.  Like Matt says, at this point we need to see real code to help you any further.

Comment: @Matt - this is a home project, I'll post some code when I get home later tonight.  @John - yes, this is a page inside a pivot.  Basically, the pivot content is set to the page whenever the pivot is selected.

Comment: @John - that's it!  On the other pages loaded into the pivot control I could override the back button, but on the landing page I had to put the event on the main page.  It seems like it should be obvious, but I kept missing it - thanks!  If you want to post the answer I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you said

> phoneapplicationpage loaded into a pivotcontrol

do you mean that the other way around? the pivot should be in the page, not the other way around. if you have a page inside the pivot, (which would really be page->pivot->page?) then the outermost page would be getting the `OnBackKeyPress`, not the inner one.

Like Matt says, at this point we need to see real code to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be a direct answer to your question, keep in mind that one of the other requirements is that when the user launches your application, then presses back once, he should always exit the application. If the first back button press will result in closing the dialog, but not exiting the app, you probably won't pass verification either.

Comment: Here's my scenario.  On the initial page load, data is pulled from a webservice.  If the webservice is unavailable, an error message pops up.  This happens on the landing page.  So, if I hit back should it close the error message and then exit?  Or just exit?  Which of the requirements does it need to meet?  Maybe I'll just need to rearchitect my application a bit to avoid this problem.

Comment: If there is no web service hence the app is useless there is no need for an extra step. Just close the app, should pass the cert IMO.

Comment: If using a custom modal dialog I would expect the back button to close that dialog before closing the app.

Comment: 5.2.4.a of the marketplace policies does not invalidate the need for pressing the back button to close custom dialogs. The intent of that clause is to ensure that it's always possible to exit back through an app by pressing the back button. The clause is there to prevent anyone making an app you can't close by using the back button.